# How to Insert Image based on the ComboBox text?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to write the vba code for inserting and changing the image inside the user form in excel but I was not able to insert as well as to change the image based on the combo box, To insert the value in combo box I have added the row source as shown in the image ( List of fruits) and to insert the images I have kept in particular folder which you can find in my program.

pl. can anybody correct me in this program or help me to get this solved so that I can get the image in the image box of the user form.

I have tried with below program

```
Private Sub UserForm_Change()

Dim k As Long, kl As Long, wa As Worksheet
Dim fg As String


fg = "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\New folder\Apple.jpg"

If Right(fg, 1) <> "\" Then
fg = fg & "\"

End If

Set wa = Sheets("Sheet1")

kl = wa.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For k = 1 To kl
Me.ComboBox2.AddItem wa.Cells(k, "A").Value

Next k

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim k As Long, kl As Long, wa As Worksheet
Dim fg As String


fg = "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\New folder"
If Right(fg, 1) <> "\" Then
fg = fg & "\"

End If

Set wa = Sheets("Sheet1")

kl = wa.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For k = 1 To kl
If Val(Me.ComboBox2.Value) = wa.Cells(k, "A").Value Then
Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fg & ".JPG")

End If

Next k

End Sub
```

Any positive responses are welcome.
Also Pl. find the images where I am trying to demonstrate.

[User form with combo box and image box][1]

[Desktop Folder Containing images in the folder][1]

Comment: I'm not seeing a UserForm_Change event on my version of Excel 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
   Dim k As Long, kl As Long, wa As Worksheet, fg As String
      
   fg = "C:\Users\mehta\Desktop\Folder for ppt images\New folder\"
   Set wa = Sheets("Sheet1")
   kl = wa.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For k = 1 To kl
      If Me.ComboBox2.Value = wa.Cells(k, "A").Value Then
         Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fg & ComboBox2.Value & ".JPG")
      End If
   Next k
   Me.Repaint
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   Dim k As Long, kl As Long, wa As Worksheet
   
   Set wa = Sheets("Sheet1")
   kl = wa.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For k = 1 To kl
      Me.ComboBox2.AddItem wa.Cells(k, "A").Value
   Next k
End Sub
```

You were missing the ComboBox2.Value in addressing the Pic
You also had a Val() function that was not helping

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tin Bum it worked for me thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: You're welcome, be great if you'd mark my answer as accepted

Comment: Sorry I was not knowing that how to mark I found it & I have marked it :)